# How to arrange shiny modules files so that they run on Shiny Server?

Tags: r, module, shiny, shiny-server, shinymodules

I am trying to put an app on the server. It is in the correct place as I've put other apps before. But, this is the first time I've used modules.

I have UI in ui.R, server in server.R and the rest (all non-reactive code + reactive functions as modules for server and UI) in global.R. All of them in the same directory. When I run it locally by runApp() it all works.

It looks as if the server does not see the global.R file or something. How should I arrange files to make it work?

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      typUI('UI_maps')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel('input.typ != "hydrologiczne"', ns = NS('UI_maps'),
                       column(6, mapUI('map1')),
                       column(6, mapUI('map2'))
      ),
      conditionalPanel('input.typ == "hydrologiczne"', ns = NS('UI_maps'),
                       column(6, mapUI('map3')),
                       column(6, mapUI('map4'))
      )
    )
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(map_m, 'map1', tabela_meteo, woj)
  callModule(map_m, 'map2', tabela_meteo, woj)
  callModule(map_h, 'map3', tabela_hydro, woj)
  callModule(map_h, 'map4', tabela_hydro, woj)
  callModule(typ, 'UI_maps', tabela_hydro, tabela_meteo)
})
```

global.R is the working implementation. When I try to connect it via a browser I get

'An error has occurred. The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization.'

No logs are being returned to the server (or I can't find them). Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

The problem was with the **sf** package which in my example uses these things:

> GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

It wasn't possible to install them on the server during a normal **sf** installation. Should've installed them manually and then change the sf package loading from **pacman::p_load()** to **library()** in order not to update these things and fail every time the app starts which is what caused crashes.